# finding specific Json field value without model class

Tags: c#, json, .net

I am looking a way to get the specific value from complex `json` without creating the Model class. I am able to read via `Newtonsoft` but with model and since I have many different `json`  model,is it possible to get the value of `content.result.id` directly ?
Is ther any way to get it as my json keeps on changing:
**Json:**

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "Type": "Test",
    "content": {
        "id": "abcd",
        "testResult": "Failed",
        "field1": {
            "id": "T1",
            "name": "T1 name"
        },
        "filed2": {
            "id": "T2",
            "name": "T2 name "
        },
        "result": {
            "id": "1111",
            "name": "T3 name"
        }
    },
    "createdAt": "2018-10-11T13:18:54.0555456+01:00",
    "updatedAt": "2018-10-11T13:18:54.0555518+01:00",
    "deleted": false,
    "_rid": "AAAA===",
    "_self": "Ab++/",
    "_etag": "\"1qw\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 12345
}
```

**Expected outcome:** 1111 (from within result)

Comment: `JObject.Parse(your-json)` then traverse the `JsonValue` manually.

Comment: Create a class with only `content` property,  and `content` has only `result` property, and `result` has only `id` property. Deserialize into such class, and you can keep it object-oriented, without worrying about malformed json when you try to access it with hard-coded way. Though you will get `content`/`result`/`id` as null, it is bit easier to debug or handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *Newtonsoft.Json*, read the JSON as `JObject` and get the value with JSON Path.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
string id = jObj.SelectToken("$.content.result.id")
    .ToString();
```

Reference: [Querying JSON with complex JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)

Comment: I used "
                    JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json.ToString());
                    string id = jObj.SelectToken("$.content.result.id")
                        .ToString();" but was getting 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.SelectToken(...) returned null.

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zcee06)

Comment: This seems your JSON does not have `content.result.id`, check whether your JSON is same as what you provided in the question. Side note, if your `json` variable is a string, you don't need the `.ToString()`.

Comment: My bad,It is rightly coming Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `System.Text.Json` you can use `JsonNode` as Follows :

```
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

var jsonObject = JsonNode.Parse(json)!.AsObject();

var id = jsonObject["content"]?["result"]?["id"];
```

or if you are using `Newtonsoft` you can use `JObject` as Follows:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var id = jsonObject["content"]?["result"]?["id"]?.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Thanks,I tried but getting 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error.After putting a debugger I saw the jsonObject have below data:https://dotnetfiddle.net/s1tJPo

Comment: The `json` you provided is different from the one you asked in the question and does not include the `reult` property, and its name has been changed to `provider` and you shoud use  `jsonObject["content"]?["provider"]?["id"]?.ToString();`.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
var resultId = parsed["content"]["result"]["id"];
```

You need to add null checking, but that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the specific JSON field value without defining a model class by using Newtonsoft's JObject class

...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string json = @"{
// JSON here
}";

JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);
string idValue = (string)jsonObj["content"]["result"]["id"];
Console.WriteLine("The ID value is: " + idValue);
```

...